# Time stamp in the C programming language

Tags: c, time, timestamp

How do I stamp two times t1 and t2 and get the difference in milliseconds in C?

Comment: You can't do that with standard C alone. The possible solutions you have will be different for Linux, Windows, mobile phones, cash registers, ..., micro wave ovens, ...

Comment: @Christoph: both time() and clock() can return -1 (cast to the appropriate type) to signify that the function is unavailable in that implementation ... and time(), when available, has a resolution of 1 second or worse. I perused the Standard but didn't find any hard limits for the clock() function

Comment: In the Linux manual page: "Note that the time can wrap around.  On a 32bit system where CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals 1000000 this function will return the same value approximately every 72 minutes." To get CPU time getrusage() is better, although clock is part of ANSI C, but getrusage/gettimeofday() not.

Answer (score 33):

This will give you the time in seconds + microseconds

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
tv.tv_sec // seconds
tv.tv_usec // microseconds
```

Answer (score 9):

Standard C99:

```
#include <time.h>

time_t t0 = time(0);
// ...
time_t t1 = time(0);
double datetime_diff_ms = difftime(t1, t0) * 1000.;

clock_t c0 = clock();
// ...
clock_t c1 = clock();
double runtime_diff_ms = (c1 - c0) * 1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

The precision of the types is implementation-defined, ie the datetime difference might only return full seconds.

Comment: The datetime difference returns full seconds at best. If I interpreted the Standard correctly, time(), when it doesn't return (time_t)-1, is not guaranteed to return new values every second: it can have a resolution of 5 seconds or 1 minute for example.

Comment: @pmg: the precision is implementations-defined, eg on my system `time()` has a `1s` resolution; the precision of `clock()` is normally as high as possible, but it measures runtime and not datetime

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find elapsed time, this method will work as long as you don't reboot the computer between the start and end.

In Windows, use GetTickCount().  Here's how:

```
DWORD dwStart = GetTickCount();
...
... process you want to measure elapsed time for
...
DWORD dwElapsed = GetTickCount() - dwStart;
```

*dwElapsed* is now the number of elapsed milliseconds.

In Linux, use *clock()* and *CLOCKS_PER_SEC* to do about the same thing.

If you need timestamps that last through reboots or across PCs (which would need quite good syncronization indeed), then use the other methods (gettimeofday()).

Also, in Windows at least you can get much better than standard time resolution.  Usually, if you called GetTickCount() in a tight loop, you'd see it jumping by 10-50 each time it changed.  That's because of the time quantum used by the Windows thread scheduler.  This is more or less the amount of time it gives each thread to run before switching to something else.  If you do a:

```
timeBeginPeriod(1);
```

at the beginning of your program or process and a:

```
timeEndPeriod(1);
```

at the end, then the quantum will change to 1 ms, and you will get much better time resolution on the GetTickCount() call.  However, this does make a subtle change to how your entire computer runs processes, so keep that in mind.  However, Windows Media Player and many other things do this routinely anyway, so I don't worry too much about it.

I'm sure there's probably some way to do the same in Linux (probably with much better control, or maybe with sub-millisecond quantums) but I haven't needed to do that yet in Linux.

Answer (score 6):

```
/*
 Returns the current time.
*/

char *time_stamp(){

char *timestamp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
time_t ltime;
ltime=time(NULL);
struct tm *tm;
tm=localtime(&ltime);

sprintf(timestamp,"%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_mon, 
    tm->tm_mday, tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
return timestamp;
}


int main(){

printf(" Timestamp: %s\n",time_stamp());
return 0;

}
```

Output: Timestamp: 20110912130940 // 2011 Sep 12 13:09:40

Comment: Instead of formatting the data, you could use asctime(tm) which returns a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use @Arkaitz Jimenez's code to get two timevals:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
//...
struct timeval tv1, tv2, diff;

// get the first time:
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);

// do whatever it is you want to time
// ...

// get the second time:
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);

// get the difference:

int result = timeval_subtract(&diff, &tv1, &tv2);

// the difference is storid in diff now.
```

Sample code for timeval_subtract can be found at [this web site](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html):

```
 /* Subtract the `struct timeval' values X and Y,
    storing the result in RESULT.
    Return 1 if the difference is negative, otherwise 0.  */

 int
 timeval_subtract (result, x, y)
      struct timeval *result, *x, *y;
 {
   /* Perform the carry for the later subtraction by updating y. */
   if (x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec) {
     int nsec = (y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec) / 1000000 + 1;
     y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
     y->tv_sec += nsec;
   }
   if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
     int nsec = (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec) / 1000000;
     y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
     y->tv_sec -= nsec;
   }

   /* Compute the time remaining to wait.
      tv_usec is certainly positive. */
   result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
   result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;

   /* Return 1 if result is negative. */
   return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
 }
```

Comment: The code in timeval_subtract is evil because it modifies the input value y. It wouldn't be bad if the inputs were two struct timeval values - as opposed to pointers. But when evaluating 'x - y', you don't normally expect the computation to alter the value stored in 'y'.

Comment: @Jonathan, true.  Though simply changing it to a pass-by-copy implementation would solve that problem

Comment: I agree.  I'd fix it, but I can't double-check that my changes would compile at the moment, so I figured I'd leave it as-is.

Answer (score 2):

how about this solution? I didn't see anything like this in my search. I am trying to avoid division and make solution simpler.

```
   struct timeval cur_time1, cur_time2, tdiff;

   gettimeofday(&cur_time1,NULL);
   sleep(1);
   gettimeofday(&cur_time2,NULL);

   tdiff.tv_sec = cur_time2.tv_sec - cur_time1.tv_sec;
   tdiff.tv_usec = cur_time2.tv_usec + (1000000 - cur_time1.tv_usec);

   while(tdiff.tv_usec > 1000000)
   {
      tdiff.tv_sec++;
      tdiff.tv_usec -= 1000000;
      printf("updated tdiff tv_sec:%ld tv_usec:%ld\n",tdiff.tv_sec, tdiff.tv_usec);
   }

   printf("end tdiff tv_sec:%ld tv_usec:%ld\n",tdiff.tv_sec, tdiff.tv_usec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also making aware of interactions between clock() and usleep(). usleep() suspends the program, and clock() only measures the time the program is running.

If might be better off to use gettimeofday() as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468596/c-programming-calculate-elapsed-time-in-milliseconds-unix)

Answer (score 0):

Use [gettimeofday()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gettimeofday) or better [clock_gettime()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime)

Answer (score 0):

U can try routines in c time library ([time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/)). Plus take a look at the [clock()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) in the same lib. It gives the clock ticks since the prog has started. But you can save its value before the operation you want to concentrate on, and then after that operation capture the cliock ticks again and find the difference between then to get the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/time.h>

time_t tm = time(NULL);
char stime[4096];
ctime_r(&tm, stime);
stime[strlen(stime) - 1] = '\0';
printf("%s",stime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This program clearly shows how to do it. Takes time 1 pauses for 1 second and then takes time 2, the difference between the 2 times should be 1000 milliseconds. So your answer is correct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// Name: miliseconds.c
// gcc /tmp/miliseconds.c -o miliseconds

struct timespec ts1, ts2; // time1 and time2

int main (void) {

    // get time1
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts1);
    sleep(1); // 1 second pause
    // get time2
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts2);
    // nanoseconds difference in mili
    long miliseconds1= (ts2.tv_nsec - ts1.tv_nsec) / 10000000 ;
    // seconds difference in mili
    long miliseconds2 = (ts2.tv_sec -  ts1.tv_sec)*1000;
    long miliseconds = miliseconds1 + miliseconds2;
    printf("%ld\n", miliseconds); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are correct, my answer was more aimed at improving AKM Mahmudul Hoque's answer than answering the original question. I was confused because they gave it 6 pts. even though your answer evidently does not directly answer the question.