# C++: How would I get unix time?

Tags: c++, unix, time, epoch

I need a function or way to get the UNIX epoch in seconds, much like how I can in PHP using the time function.

I can't find any method except the time() in ctime which seems to only output a formatted date, or the clock() function which has seconds but seems to always be a multiple of 1 million, nothing with any resolution.

I wish to measure execution time in a program, I just wanted to calculate the diff between start and end; how would a C++ programmer do this?

EDIT: time() and difftime only allow resolution by seconds, not ms or anything too btw.

Comment: Do you want something better than second precision, but measured in seconds?

Comment: You pose unrelated requirements. You say you want unix epoch in seconds, and you say you want to measure performance/execution time. These two things are normally achieved by different means.

Answer (score 2):

[time()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) should work fine, use [difftime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) for difference of time calculations. In case you need better resolutuion, use [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday).

Also, duplicate of: [Calculating elapsed time in a C program in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468596/c-programming-calculate-elapsed-time-in-milliseconds-unix)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to profile get, I'd recommend using [getrusage](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getrusage.html).  This will allow you to track CPU time instead of wall clock time:

```
struct rusage ru;
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ru);

ru.ru_utime.tv_sec;  // seconds of user CPU time
ru.ru_utime.tv_usec; // microseconds of user CPU time
ru.ru_stime.tv_sec;  // seconds of system CPU time
ru.ru_stime.tv_usec; // microseconds of system CPU time
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you.

`time_t epoch = time(0);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    time_t time = time(0);
    cout<<time<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions, feel free to comment below.