# Can't measure time cost using libpq

Tags: postgresql

I want to measure how much time a query cost, so I have code below:

```
struct timespec vartime = timer_start();  
res=PQexec(conn, "...");
long time_elapsed_nanos = timer_end(vartime);
printf("Time taken (ns), %ld\n",time_elapsed_nanos);
```

however, the output is very small, say, 0.05ms. But in terminal, if I use explain analyze it shows 400ms.

why I could not measure the cost using code above? what should I do? thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The `timer_start()` and `timer_end()` functions are not part of the C standard library, and it's unclear what the first one does. `struct timespec` holds an elapsed time, so having `timer_start()` returning that type is suspicious. Since what other point in time would it be counting?

I'd suggest to use a piece of code based on `gettimeofday()`, as shown in one answer of:

[Calculating elapsed time in a C program in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468834/238814)

`PQexec()` is a blocking call, so measuring the time will work the same as for some long CPU calculation that the above technique uses as a demo.