# HOW I CALCULATE TIME IN C PROGRAM

Tags: c, linux, time, parallel-processing

**how i calculate real time in a program of c ....**

__________________________start=clock();
----------------------------end=clock();

diff=end-start;

start=124682129.0000000
end =124682129.0000000
result value of diff is 0.0000000000000000000000

i am sorting an array i want to calculate time before sort and end of sort in gcc compiler ......

**how i can calculate these times?
real time
execution time**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating elapsed time in a C program in milliseconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468596/calculating-elapsed-time-in-a-c-program-in-milliseconds)

Comment: Did you try to google it first? it's a pretty common question with many answers online, you should ask here only when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the execution time of your program, you can do this:

```
//some code
#include <time.h>

int main () { 
    double seconds;
    time_t started=time(NULL);
    RunSomeFunc();
    seconds=difftime(time(NULL),started);
    //more code
}
```

Here you're measuring the execution time of `RunSomeFunc`.

---

#### Docs

- [`difftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/)
- [`ctime` a.k.a `time.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)

Answer (score 0):

simple program to print time in C

```
/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```