# Easiest way to do a millisecond countdown in C?

Tags: c, time

What is the easiest way to do a milliseconds countdown in C (min:sec:milliseconds) and display it on screen ? I just need to execute the program into a cmd prompt window and see the seconds:milliseconds in order to measure precise time between screenshots.

Comment: The details of the high precision timer vary by hardware and operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval ss1, ss2;
ss1.tv_usec; // first timestamp
gettimeofday(&ss1,NULL);

//Write code of screenshot capture

ss2.tv_usec; // second timestamp
gettimeofday(&ss2,NULL);
```

Note that `tv_usec` will give you the time in microseconds and `1 millisecond = 1000 microseconds`.

Check [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444428/time-stamp-in-the-c-programming-language) for other similar solutions.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain correctly, I just need to run the program into a cmd prompt window and the program should display the timer min:sec:milliseconds elapsed since the start of the program. So should I just do `printf("%d", ss1);` ?

Comment: `ss1.tv_usec` will give you the timestamp in microseconds. Once you calculate the difference between the two timestamps in microseconds, you can convert this result to min:sec:milliseconds by dividing the number accordingly, i.e. divide it by 60000000 to get minutes, divide the remainder of that by 1000000 to get seconds, and lastly divide the remainder of that by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Comment: I see so basically I need to do an infinite loop that runs every ms (or few ms) and display the counter. Do you know what I should use to stop the infinite loop for 1 or few ms ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your application is, so its hard to help with that. You could use an if condition to break out of the loop (maybe write this code in a separate function and return its value when the `condition` is true.

Comment: I want to use a pause function so my program don't use all CPU, is there a function like SDL_Delay() that takes a float ?

Comment: You could use the `usleep()` function available in the `#include<unistd.h>` header. This function takes only int parameters in microseconds though and works only on Unix-based systems.
To implement the same in Windows systems, you could use `Sleep()` (case-sensitive) which is part of `#include<windows.h>` directive which takes int parameters in milliseconds.